# Last letter changing in php if tag

Tags: php

I have a 3 button and I want to change target links for each one. I used $z variable for it but I have a *weird* problem.

Here it is my button code:

```
<button target="blank" href="<?php echo $z ?>" class="prev" name='prev'/>
```

I defined $z at the top of the page

```
$z = 0;
```

This is my if statement:

```
$z++;

if ( $z == 1 ){
$z = "google";
}
elseif($z==2) {
$z = "twitter";
}
elseif($z==3) {
$z = "behance";
}
```

But weird point is in source code my href links showing like this:

```
<button target="blank" href="google" class="prev" name="prev"></button>
<button target="blank" href="googlf" class="prev" name="prev"></button>
<button target="blank" href="googlg" class="prev" name="prev"></button>
```

It changing last letter but why? Can you help me with this please?

Thank you for reading it.

Comment: Show the entire code on how you are generating the button. Are you using a loop?

Comment: Make sure to close your echo statement with a semicolon.
<button target="blank" href="<?php echo $z; ?>" class="prev" name='prev'/>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use different variables for the counter and the link.
Right now you are setting $z to 'google' and then later on you add 1 to it. That makes the string change. Try this

```
$z++;
$link = '';

if ( $z == 1 ){
$link = "google";
}
elseif($z==2) {
$link = "twitter";
}
elseif($z==3) {
$link = "behance";
}
```

then use $link in your HTML

An even better way to do it would be by using switch() instead of if

```
switch ( $z ) {
  case 1 :
     $link = "google";
     break;
  case 2 :
     $link = "twitter";
     break;
  case 3 :
    $link = "behance";
    break;
}
```

Comment: Yes, it works! Thank you so much, I appreciate for your help :)